# Convert continuous distribution in discrete distribution

Tags: probability

How to correctly convert continuous distribution in discrete distribution? Can you suggest some articles or books at this theme?

Comment: Correct with respect to what?

Comment: The conversion should be mathematically proved and provable.

Comment: Do you mean something like: Binomial and Normal distribution?

Comment: Actually, there isn't one. Unless I am much mistaken. The relation between continuous and discrete is not 1:1. You can easily go from discrete to continuous, but not back. Any operator you may use, may bias the results. Like rounding will bias values if the continuous favors values `a+0.5 <= x <= b-0.5`, rounding will favor `b`, and not `a`, even if the pmf says they both are equally likely. And so on.

Comment: It was four years ago. How fast life flies! I were finding the best approximation method for continuous distribution.